# Solve $|x-2| \leq 2|x|$

Tags: calculus, inequality

This is an in-class example we were given in calculus class, I am having some difficulty understanding one of the instructor's steps.

The following is my attempt of the question:

Since this is an inequality we must answer in two cases:

Case 1:  $x \geq 0 $

Thus, $x-2 \leq 2x$

(rearrange for) $x \geq -2$

Therefore we know that $x > 0$.

Case 2: $x < 0$

Thus, $-x+2 \leq -2x$

(rearrange for)$ x \leq -2$

Therefore we know $x \leq -2$.

Thus, my final answer was that  $x$ is less than $-2$, and greater than or equal to $0$.

The instructor however included a third case that we must consider:

[case 3: $0 \leq x \leq 2$)  He said that we must check all "switching points" ($0$ and $2$ were the switching points in this example).

It was not explained how these switching points were determined.  Past examples that were similar did not include a step for finding "switching points" and instead only considered when x was greater than (or equal) to $0$ or less than (or equal) to $0$, and so I went ahead and went through this process.

Please explain why we need to check the case where $ 0 \leq x \leq 2$, and how we check these "switching points".

Comment: FYI, you can avoid this "switching point" business by recognizing that $|x-2| \leq 2|x|$ if and only if $(x-2)^2 \leq 4x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the very first line of your analysis in Case 1. Assuming $x\geq0$ does not allow you to drop all the absolute value bars, because $x-2$ could be either positive or negative under this assumption, and so $|x-2|$ is not always equal to $x-2$.

To drop the absolute value bars you need to make assumptions that allow you decide the sign of both $x-2$ and $x$. So you should look at three cases: $x$ is at least 2, $x$ is between 0 and 2 inclusive, and $x$ is at most 0. Convince yourself that in each of these cases you can decide the sign of both $x-2$ and $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Your cases aren't quite right. Try these instead:

Case 1: If $x \geq 2$, then  $|x-2| = x-2$ and $|x| = x$.

Case 2: If $0 \leq x \leq 2$, then $|x-2| = -(x-2)$ and $|x| = x$.

Case 3: If $x \leq 0$, then $|x-2| = -(x-2)$ and $|x| = -x$.

The reason we need to consider different cases is because we want to be able to remove the absolute values. But in order to do that, we need to know whether $|x|$ should be replaced with $x$ or $-x$. This depends on whether $x$ is positive or negative, respectively.

Similarly, whether $|x-2|$ should be replaced with $x-2$ or $-(x-2)$ depends on whether $x-2$ is positive or negative, or equivalently, whether $x \geq 2$ or $x \leq 2$.

This explains why we need to consider the "switching points" $x=0$ and $x=2$.

One might think that there would be four cases, since $x$ can be either positive or negative, and $x-2$ can be either positive or negative. But in fact, one of these cases is impossible: we can't have both $x \leq 0$ and $x \geq 2$. So that leaves three possibilities:

1. $x \geq 0$ and $x - 2 \geq 0$. This is simply the case $x \geq 2$. The fact that $x \geq 0$ is redundant.
2. $x \geq 0$ and $x - 2 \leq 0$. Equivalently, $0 \leq x \leq 2$.
3. $x \leq 0$ and $x - 2 \leq 0$. This is simply the case $x \leq 0$. The fact that $x \leq 2$ is redundant.

One final remark: at the boundary between two cases, it makes no difference which case you use. For example, if $x=0$ then we can replace $|x|$ with either $x$ or $-x$. So it doesn't matter that the cases overlap at the endpoints.

Comment: This is not an explanation; you've merely repeated what the instructor told him.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: No, I corrected what his instructor told him. (Or corrected his mistranslation, as the case may be.) I'll add some more explanatory remarks, though.

Comment: I have no idea what your comment means, because what the instructor said is not incorrect. The student was told to check a third case, and he asked why he had to check the third case. Telling him "your cases aren't quite right," and showing the three cases, is telling him something he already knows. There is an answer embedded in your casework, but better to make it explicit.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: What he wrote for his first case, $x \geq 0$, is not correct. It should have been $x \geq 2$.

Comment: It is clear that is the student's work, not the instructor's... But fine. Either way, your answer now counts as an explanation, not simply a restatement of what the instructor told him.